# Error generating (Java )Webservice client in Eclipse from .Net Web Service WSDL error

Tags: eclipse, web-services, webservice-client

When trying to generate web service client in Eclipse using Wizard/Web services/web service client from an existing .Net Web services' WSDL, I encountered the following error:
 **"Wizard WSDL validation is disabled."**, the wizard could not continue back to the main page since:
 **No server can be found and WebServiceProject does not exist. Choose an existing project or use the preferences to configure a server runtime.**
What could I do so solve this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Does the Profile validation and conformance section on [This Eclipse Page](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/ws/scenarios/prefs.html) help?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, i son't even see part of the configuraton shown in your link. This is really giving me a headache. Why does it seem Apache needs to be installed in order to get a simple soap client working.